# configure and run scheduled tasks (Cron Jobs!) using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, scheduled-tasks, pyrocms

I want to build a section at admin panel to give the ability to configure the scheduled tasks.

Idea :

at that panel:

- admin can upload a php file  (I can do this)
- make a schedule (i.e. once a week at friday 12:00) (I can do this)
- assign a schedule to an uploaded php file (I can do this)
- execute the php file at the scheduled times.( this is my question)

The real question is how to schedule and execute the php file without forcing admin of the site to use cPanel or ssh?

I hope the question be clear.
btw, I am using pyrocms(if needed)

Comment: so you want to write a cron interface in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037176/install-a-cron-job-with-a-php-script

Answer (score -1):

You can write a bash script that gets values from each shedule and its file, and use `cron` to execute it on the background.