# How to setup cron jobs on Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I developed notification.php to send a notification email to the users and I it works successfully inside a page of my web site now I want to create a cron job to run this page in regular time not associated to refreshing that page. I have not done this before and I barely know cron jobs

After watching this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-UZsAk_UiE

Where can I find cPanel?

My System specifications are:

1- MySQL database

2- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037176/install-a-cron-job-with-a-php-script

Comment: If you're running on Windows, then look for "Task Scheduler" on the Windows Control Panel.... you should find it under System/Admin Tools

Comment: @satishrajak: cron jobs don't run on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install cPanel on Windows. It's Linux only. Windows uses "Task Scheduler". You might want to check this out: https://support.qualityunit.com/384836-How-to-set-up-cron-job-on-a-Windows-server